# Grid inside Table or MainTable

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have one WWSD or one SDPanel with some attributes but between these attributes that are fixed inside a Table or directly in the MainTable I want put and Grid, the problem is that the Grid is not showed and when I put the grid its no more possible scroll in the WWSD or SDPanel, is like the Grid stuck the SDPanel more than the grid is not showed.

Anyone can help me to put the Grid and keep with all normally ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're targeting Android.

The issue is that Android does not natively support nested scrolling. Therefore, a GeneXus layout that contains a grid will disable the form's own scrolling (so that the grid can itself scroll).

There are two ways of resolving this issue:

- Redesign the panel so that the form does not vertically exceed the size of the screen (thus, form scrolling is not necessary).
- Set **autogrow=true** for the grid, which will resize to fit all items (and "push down" any other controls located below it). Since the grid will no longer need to scroll, the form's scroll will be enabled.

Comment: matiash, thank you so much by your answer by your comment about the autogrow I made more tests and got solution put every elements MainTable, Grid and Table of Grid with autogrow true ;-) thank you